# How to prove $\left\lceil\frac{x}y\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y\right\rfloor+1$ for positive integers $x,y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have to prove that

$$\left\lceil\frac{x}y\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y\right\rfloor+1\;?$$

For any positive integers $x, y$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked a few cases? Seen what happens?

Comment: The statement is false for $x=1,y=\frac12$

Comment: Do you have to prove this for *integer* $x, y$?

Comment: You probably want to specify that $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: @6005: Not true for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}$ (i.e., false for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}$).

Comment: @barakmanos Good point you are correct. But $x$ can be negative, just not $y$.

Answer (score 4):

For this to be true, **you need to specify that $\boldsymbol{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\boldsymbol{y > 0}$.**

Then: if
$$
\left\lceil \frac{x}{y} \right\rceil = m
$$
then
$$
m - 1 < \frac{x}{y} \le m
$$
which means
$$
my - y < x \le my.
$$
which we can rewrite
$$
my  -y \le x - 1 < my
$$
since $x$ is an integer and both bounds are integers.

Can you finish? You need to reach the conclusion that
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{y} \right\rfloor = m - 1.
$$

Comment: oh i see, sorry

Answer (score 1):

As @6005 clearly said, you need to agree that the $x,y$ are positive integers with the constraint $y \gt 0$.

This is a hint regarding the right side of the inequality:

> $$\left\lceil\frac{x}y\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y\right\rfloor+1=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y+1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1+y}y\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y-1}y\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y} + 1 - \frac{1}y\right\rfloor$$

Comment: The statement $\lceil x/y \rceil = \lfloor x/ y + 1\rfloor$ is only true if $x/y$ is not an integer.

Comment: Your modification did not fix it :)

Comment: @6005 you were right, thank you for the feedback! I have removed that part of the explanation, I am keeping the part that can help to study what happens with the right side term.

Comment: Well you were almost there before, if you just split into cases based on whether or not $\frac{x}{y}$ was an integer.

Comment: @6005 good hint for the OP, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=py+q$, with $0\le q<y$.

Then if $q=0$,
$$\left\lceil\frac{x}y\right\rceil=p,\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y\right\rfloor+1=p+\left\lfloor\frac{y-1}y\right\rfloor+1=p.$$
and if $q>0$,

$$\left\lceil\frac{x}y\right\rceil=p+1,\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}y\right\rfloor+1=p+\left\lfloor\frac{q-1}y\right\rfloor+1=p+1.$$